# CSV processing - strip some chars and combine files

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd, csv

I have several dozen CSV files in a folder. I need to:

1. Strip out null characters (\x00)
2. Make sure there is only one CRLF at the end (sometimes there are 0, 1 or more)
3. Combine all the files into one file. Each file has a header, but only want one header for the combined file.
4. [Optional: Newer csv's have an additional column. Possible to add new column (w blanks) for older files?]

Have this so far for combining and keeping only one header:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set first=1
set fileName="combined.csv"
>%fileName% (
  for %%F in (*.csv) do (
    if not "%%F"==%fileName% (
      if defined first (
        type "%%F"
        set "first="
      ) else more +1 "%%F"
    )
  )
)
```

Not sure how to replace / strip characters though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work using `GnuSED`.  Sed removes the nul characters and all extra blank lines, after adding a CRLF to the end of each file during copying.

`More` has a bug at 64K lines in each file where it will pause, and it also translates TABs to spaces, if that is an issue.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set first=1
>"combined.bin" (
for %%F in (*.csv) do (
    if defined first (
        type "%%F"
        set "first="
      ) else (
     more +1 "%%F"
    )
   echo(
  )
)
sed -e "/^$/"d -e "s/\x00//g" < "combined.bin" > "combined.csv"
del "combined.bin"
```